# Specify the location to save the pdf file asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, directory, adobe

Below is my code which generates a sample PDF file. However the server.mappath method saves the file at the project folder. How do i allow the PDF file to be saved in my own desktop?

```
protected void btnPDF_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        var document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 50, 50, 25, 25);
        var filename = DDLCase.SelectedItem.Text + ".pdf";
        var output = new FileStream(Server.MapPath(filename), FileMode.Create);
        var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, output);
        document.Open();
        var welcomeParagraph = new Paragraph("Test1");
        document.Add(welcomeParagraph);
        document.Close();
        btnPDF.Enabled= false;
    }
```

Comment: "saved in a desktop" - why do you think that location on server is better than any other (plus some accounts may not have correctly populated "desktop")... Or you want to cause save dialog in browser? Or you want to use server side code to save to desktop on user's machine?

Comment: try for `string fileName = Path.Combine(@"C:\Users\username\Desktop", filename);` or try for `VirtualPathUtility`.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Actually, i'm currently just trying out the basics of PDF file on a localhost. So i'm just trying to figure out a way to save the PDF file in any location to desktop on user's machine.

Comment: Specify location you want and save there... Or you I miss something? To make the question "specify desktop location" answerable you need to specify what user account should be used to find desktop folder (current? one of process runs under? yours?).

Comment: My question here is actually very simple. As you can see from my codes, my PDF file is automatically generated in my project file. I'm trying to enquire if there is any other way for me to save my PDF file in another location. It may not be necessarily at the desktop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is very unclear what your problem is as it should be pretty straightforward to replace `Server.MapPath(filename)` with some other location.

One useful function is [Path.Combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx) so you can correctly build path to a file:

```
   var output = new FileStream(Path.Combine("c:\\myPDF\\", filename), FileMode.Create);
```

Note that to be done properly folder on server where you plan to store files must have enough permissions to allow ASP.Net process to save files there. If you use Windows auth with impersonation it becomes trickier as account code is running under during request will be incoming user's account.

Comment: It might be straightforward to you but otherwise for me as i'm just a student still trying to learn and explore about asp.net, c# and pdf. But nevertheless, i must thank you for your help. I have added my desktop directory "C:\Users\apr12mpsip\Desktop" but i have this error such as "Unrecognized escape sequence". I copied the file directory directly from my window explorer.

Comment: @TeoChuenWeiBryan - Learning to use search engines is important - http://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+Unrecognized+escape+sequence  (please also consider reading on basic C# types like `string` and how string literals can be represented).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   public string CommonFileSave(HttpPostedFileBase postedFile, string filePath)       
   {
        string resultResponse = "sccuess";

        if (!Directory.Exists(filePath))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(filePath);
            postedFile.SaveAs(filePath + postedFile.FileName);
        }
        else
        {
            filePath = filePath + postedFile.FileName;
            if (!System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                postedFile.SaveAs(filePath);
            }
        }
        return resultResponse;
    }
```